# C# Delegating Members - Resharper

Tags: c#, resharper, delegation

[Resharper can create Delegating Members](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Code_Generation__Delegating_Members.html) (Alt + Ins)

But what are delegating members?

Most of the searches I do come up with American Politics which is not useful.

Comment: This SO-Answer explains it: [distinguishing between delegation, composition and aggregation][1]



  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1384426/distinguishing-between-delegation-composition-and-aggregation-java-oo-design

Comment: That explained it well. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Delegating methods are simply methods that tunnel directly through to some contained object.

For instance:

```
class MyClass
{
    private SomeType innerObj = new SomeType();
    public Bar GetFoo()
    {
        return innerObj.GetFoo();
    }

}
```

Comment: Oh my god. Just thinking about the wasted hours setting up proxys makes me wish I had known this earlier

Comment: Yep. A real life saver if you need to make proxies, facades and the like.